# Trouble with sources.list and apt-get update in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, repository

I am facing with a problem in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I am running Ubuntu in my virtual machine.

I am having a problem with `sudo apt-get update` command. This is the current output I get:

```
VirtualBox@VirtualBox:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Hit:3 https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian bionic InRelease       
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease             
Hit:5 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_12.x bionic InRelease                    
Hit:6 https://dnw9lb6lzp2d8.cloudfront.net stable InRelease                    
Reading package lists... Done
```

I realized that `apt-get` issues are most of the time related with `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Then I followed the solution here: [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories) to restore default repositories in `sources.list`.

But I guess it didn't work because this is the content of `sources.list`:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security universe main
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe main
```

My questions here are:

- Is the result of `sudo apt-get update` normal? Is it really
  updating? Why it doesn't do Fetching anymore?
- I opened the Software & Updates to fix the repositories in `/etc/apt/sources.list` just like the first answer here [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories) Do you think now content of the `sources.list` is normal?

It would be so nice if some expert could answer my questions and direct me in the correct path. Because I am new in Ubuntu and I can't solve every problem on my own.

Thank you so much for your support!!

Comment: I can't see any problems. The output is OK. It won't "fetch" anything if there is nothing new there.